# Exporter classification_signature

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I'm trying to modify the [serving tutorial](https://tensorflow.github.io/serving/serving_basic) to work with my model, which is basically the CIFAR example modified to work with a CSV file and JPEGs. I can't seem to find the documentation for the Exporter class, but here is what I have so far. It's in the train() function in the cifar10_train.py file:

```
  # Save the model checkpoint periodically.
  if step % 10 == 0 or (step + 1) == FLAGS.max_steps:
    checkpoint_path = os.path.join(FLAGS.train_dir, 'model.ckpt')
    saver.save(sess, checkpoint_path, global_step=step)

    export_dir = FLAGS.export_dir
    print 'Exporting trained model to ' + FLAGS.export_dir
    export_saver = tf.train.Saver(sharded=True)
    model_exporter = exporter.Exporter(export_saver)
    #
    # TODO: where to find x and y?
    #
    signature = exporter.classification_signature(input_tensor=x, scores_tensor=y)
    model_exporter.init(sess.graph.as_graph_def(),
                        default_graph_signature=signature)
    model_exporter.export(export_dir, tf.constant(FLAGS.export_version), sess)
```

Here is the code I use to train the model:

```
  labels = numpy.fromfile(os.path.join(data_dir, 'labels.txt'), dtype=numpy.int32, count=-1, sep='\n')

  filenames_and_labels = []

  start_image_number = 1
  end_image_number = 8200

  for i in xrange(start_image_number, end_image_number):
    file_name = os.path.join(data_dir, 'image%d.jpg' % i)
    label = labels[i - 1]
    filenames_and_labels.append(file_name + "," + str(label))


  print('Reading filenames for ' + str(len(filenames_and_labels)) + ' files (from ' + str(start_image_number) + ' to ' + str(end_image_number) + ')')

  for filename_and_label in filenames_and_labels:
    array = filename_and_label.split(",")
    f = array[0]
    # print(array)
    if not tf.gfile.Exists(f):
      raise ValueError('Failed to find file: ' + f)

  # Create a queue that produces the filenames to read.
  filename_and_label_queue = tf.train.string_input_producer(filenames_and_labels)

  filename_and_label_tensor = filename_and_label_queue.dequeue()
  filename, label = tf.decode_csv(filename_and_label_tensor, [[""], [""]], ",")
  file_contents = tf.read_file(filename)
  image = tf.image.decode_jpeg(file_contents)
```

Any ideas how I can set up Exporter correctly?

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the [MNIST export example](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/example/mnist_export.py).

That shows how x and y are generated then placed in the signature.

Also, the [Inception example](https://github.com/tensorflow/serving/blob/master/tensorflow_serving/example/inception_export.py) shows how to extend an existing model to create exports and serving.  In particular the `cifar10.inference` call looks similar to `inception_model.inference`.